# Detecting active virtual desktop on Windows 10 - Task View - virtual desktop switcher

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10

Windows 10 provide for users switching between virtual desktops using Task View.

For developing purpose, I need to:

- detect which virtual desktop is active
- get virtual desktop parameters (handle, class, position, styles)
- get list of applications from this virtual desktop
- move application from one virtual desktop to another

How can I do that? Is there any API?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Answer (score 5):

There is an interface that should provide most of the functionality you need: [IVirtualDesktopManager interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It has the following methods:

- GetWindowDesktopId
- IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop
- MoveWindowToDesktop

In case that wasn't enough, there are even more unofficial APIs documented on this Russian website http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/105416/blog3671.html

Edit: here's a C# wrapper library for all the COM interfaces: https://github.com/Grabacr07/VirtualDesktop

Comment: Here's an app I built from Grabacr07's API wrapper.....https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop

Comment: FYI: ^ zVirtualDesktop mentioned by MichaelZ is now closed-source and commercial. Some code is stil lin github's history, see "closing sources" commit.