# Show window of app on all desktops in Windows, but programmatically

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, windows-10, virtual-desktop

I am trying to develop a software (using ElectronJS) that would assist in dragging and dropping content across windows and virtual Desktops, in Windows.

However, for it to work, I must be able to display the same window across all the virtual desktops/workspaces. I could easily implement it for Linux and MacOS, using `window.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true)`. But in Windows, I would have to make the user manually open task view, right click on the window, and enable "Show Windows from this App on all Desktops".

Is there a way to have that enabled via programming, so that I can write it in the program code itself? System commands, or API functions (if any) would be appreciated.

I'm using Electron v13.1.2, node v12.8.2, npm v6.14.5

Comment: No ready to use solution for you, but you may want to check the code of this application: https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop - see "What is the difference between pin app and pin window?" - it seems that it already contains the functionality you want, and the code is somewhere there. Commits around https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop/commit/927cea203fc3c4c80406c7a168bc2c0dee12fc8b were the last usable ones, so you could check older history, maybe the feature is there.

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32268671/717732 and the lone comment there suggests that "Michael Z" (https://stackoverflow.com/users/4114591/michael-z) is the author of that zVirtualDesktop, and that it is based on https://github.com/Grabacr07/VirtualDesktop

Comment: have you found any solution for this in electron?